# Change the firebase configuration in Angular at runtime

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I have an angular application with Firebase backend using AngularFire. There're 3 firebase configurations (prod, dev, QA), and I want to be able to switch between them on the HTML page by choosing an option from a dropdown. How can I implement this?

I've searched all over Google (even asked ChatGPT and Bard), and none of the solutions worked. Most of them use outdated versions of AngularFire, so their functions don't work.

Comment: You must initialize a new app object for each different project you want to use, then switch between those apps dynamically throughout your app.

Comment: @DougStevenson you mean initialize a new app object in the "imports" section of app.module.ts? As in, call AngularFireModule.initializeApp(....) multiple times?

Comment: You can do it any way you want. I'm not familiar with Angular.